# How do I get rid of error "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command" when running 'npm install' for MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, express, stack, npm, mean-stack

downloaded mean stck zip from mean.io
did an npm install
after few minutes I got an error. Please see screenshot. what do I do?

[image: screenshot]

```
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/event-emitter/-/event-e
mitter-0.2.2.tgz

> mean@1.0.0 postinstall C:\ss\D1\google\04\mean\mean-stack
> ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like mean stacks postinstall script is hardcoded with Unix style paths. In Unix `./somethig/or/another` signifies accessing the `something` directory starting HERE (the meaning of `.`).

I'd suggest submitting a bug on their GitHub page to start. Then you might be able to get away with editing the `package.json` to have the post install script use Windows style paths. It would be something like `node_modules\bower\bin\bower install`. I don't have windows so cannot say for certain.

Comment: changing the path to windows style worked for me. Note you have to double up the slashes: node_modules\\bower\\bin\\bower . Unfortunateally I need this work work on both unix and windows

Answer (score 5):

If you want to call something from `node_modules/bin`, you don't have to point at it directly. You can just call the tool by name in NPM script definition, i.e.:

```
"postinstall": "bower install"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Unfortunately Windows PowerShell tells me "bower is not recognized", but I've `npm install`ed everything. Any ideas what to try?

Answer (score 2):

The postinstall doesn't work really well now for this repository on Windows. Try to run `npm install -g bower` and then `bower install` in the project's folder. It should do the same thing without postinstall.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error while running `npm run env`.

```
> ergonode-front@1.1.0 env
> ./lib/index.js env

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What I did was manually going to directory and run the command. Like this,

```
cd ./lib
node index.js env
```