# Webstorm,nodejs, npm test, '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, webstorm

I'm new to nodejs, working on **Webstorm 9.0.1**, i'm trying to use Lab module for tests using this tutorial https://medium.com/the-spumko-suite/testing-hapi-services-with-lab-96ac463c490a

My package.json file contains the following :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/lab/bin/lab -c"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "hapi": "^8.0.0",
    "joi": "^5.0.2",
    "lab": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

The local node_modules directory is created in the directory `C:\Users\DT002\WebstormProjects\hapiB\test>`

the problem is that when i try to test, i got the following error :

```
> C:\Users\DT002\WebstormProjects\hapiB\test>npm test
> 
> test@1.0.0 test C:\Users\DT002\WebstormProjects\hapiB\test
> ./node_modules/lab/bin/lab -c

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413157/how-do-i-get-rid-of-error-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comm: you need to remove './' and change path separators

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in your scripts runs as a commands in the terminal. You have in your `npm test`: `"./node_modules/lab/bin/lab -c"`.

What the system is complaining is the first dot that you have there. You can remove the `./` and the error will go away.

```
{ "test": "node_modules/lab/bin/lab -c" }
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the following:  C:\Users\DT002\WebstormProjects\hapiB\test>npm test  > test@1.0.0 test C:\Users\DT002\WebstormProjects\hapiB\test  > node_modules/lab/bin/lab -c  **'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**
operable program or batch file.  npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.  npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: since it is windows, don't you need to have the bars pointing to the left? \ instead of / ?